# Mod Rewrite not working and I can't work out why

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been going around in circles for hours now and I am hoping that someone can clarify exactly what is going on.

This customer has just moved from a Static website to a Wordpress website and they want to update paths on their site so that any links to old pages go to the new site instead.

So, for example, this page:

http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/timetables/service_106.html

Will, instead link to this page:

http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/compass-timetables/bus-timetables/

If you try clicking on the first link, you will still get the old page. I have used many different guides and techniques but I am still unable to make it work.

So far, .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 /timetables/(.*) /compass-timetables/bus-timetables/$1
RewriteRule   ^/timetables/(.+)  http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/compass-timetables/bus-timetables/$1  [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But as you can see, that isn't working.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: I've used the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin in the past for a site that required a lot of redirected pages. If you end up requiring rewrite rules for a lot of pages it might save you some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^timetables/(.+)$ /compass-timetables/bus-timetables/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can see what you did to, refining the rule and ensuring that the rewrite is 'on' first of all.
Thank you.
Rob